Solana/Web3.js recreate a program interaction Transaction
I'd like to replicate with Solana/Web3.js library the same program interaction of this transaction: https://solscan.io/tx/4a88FUdQyn2oLP8vJQLnxed6QAxSXuyH4HJHFRz9nuF3RHEXC8hYkj4E9uEvpv2uJVR5RKfPCMDKx5WTWyk8VkSV
In particular, I can replicate the Compute Budget, the SOL Transfer, the SyncNative and the two Create Associated Account, but what about Istruction #6?
I cannot find out whether it's possible. Can you give me some info to get to the right way please?
Thank you

Looking at that program on the explorer https://explorer.solana.com/address/BGm96W3adqiQvH152ayuudzUEvaoMWJfqWy2QqdKvzd8, it doesn't seem to have an Anchor IDL published, meaning that you'll need to go searching for a JS library to interact with their program.
It links to something called "Solana Pad", but their docs don't seem to have any dev info unfortunately https://solanapad.gitbook.io/docs
It seems like they want to encourage people to use their website as much as possible, unfortunately!
